# Sigma algebra generated by sum of two indicator functions

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Lets say I have a random variable $X = 1_{(a,b)} + 1_{(c,d)}$ where $(a,b), (c,d)$ are disjoint. I wanna determine $\sigma (X)$. Well what is the easist/best approach to this? I can determine $\sigma (1_{(a,b)})$ and $\sigma (1_{(c,d)})$
is that useful to then determine $\sigma (X)$ or do I have to do it by "bruteforce"?

Comment: Perhaps redundant but what is $\sigma(X)$ defined as?

Comment: The smallest sigma algebra such that $X$ is measurable. I now how to make them each measureable, and sum of measureable is measureable. @Wolfy

Comment: Ok, I recall that. Let me think about this and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the $\sigma$-algebra you want to endow the target with. Since this wasn't specified in your question, I just assumed that the target $\mathbb{R}$ is endowed with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Let $S$ be a set. For any function $X:S\to\mathbb{R}$ note that $\sigma(X)=X^{-1}(\mathcal{B})=\{X^{-1}(A)~:~A\in\mathcal{B}\},$ where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$. This should be clear since $X$ is measurable with respect to some $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak{M}$ if and only if $X^{-1}(\mathcal{B})\subseteq\mathfrak{M}$. Also note that this is a $\sigma$-algebra since countable unions, countable intersections, and complements are preserved under the inverse image.

Now we consider your case when $S=\mathbb{R}$ and $X=\mathbf{1}_{(a,b)}+\mathbf{1}_{(c,d)}.$ Note that for any $A\in\mathcal{B}$ we have $$X^{-1}(A)=\begin{cases}\mathbb{R}\setminus((a,b)\cup(c,d)) & 0\in A,1\notin A,\\
(a,b)\cup(c,d) & 0\notin A,1\in A,\\
\mathbb{R} & 0\in A,1\in A\\
\emptyset & 0\notin A,1\notin A \end{cases},$$
and so we see that $\sigma(X)=\{\emptyset,\mathbb{R},(a,b)\cup(c,d),\mathbb{R}\setminus((a,b)\cup(c,d))\}.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space and $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ a random variable. By the very definition, $\sigma(X)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ on $\Omega$ such that $X$ is $\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable.

Since $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are disjoint, the random variable $X = 1_{(a,b)} + 1_{(c,d)}$ takes only the values $0$ and $1$. Therefore $X$ is measurable with respect to a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ if, and only if,

$$\{X=0\} \in \mathcal{F} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \{X=1\} \in \mathcal{F}.$$

As $\{X=0\} = \{X=1\}^c$ this is equivalent to

$$\{X=1\} \in \mathcal{F}.$$

This means that the *smallest* $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ such that $X$ is $\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$-measurable is given by

$$\mathcal{F} = \sigma(\{X=1\}) = \sigma((a,b) \cup (c,d)).$$

Hence,

$$\sigma(X) = \sigma((a,b) \cup (c,d)).$$

Answer (score 0):

For any random variable $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ it can be shown that: $$\sigma(X)=\{\{X\in B\}\mid B\in\mathcal B\}\tag1$$

Here $\mathcal B$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets on $\mathbb R$.

$\sigma(X)$ is by definition the *smallest* $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ such that $X$ is measurable with respect to it.

It is evident that for every $B\in\mathcal B$ we must have $\{X\in B\}\in\sigma(X)$.

On the other hand it is not difficult to prove that the RHS of $(1)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

These two facts imply $(1)$.

In your case we have $\{X\in\{0,1\}\}=\Omega$ so that $\{X\in B\}=\{X\in B\cap\{0,1\}\}$.

This leads to: $$\sigma(X)=\{\{X\in B\}\mid B\in\wp(\{0,1\})\}=\{\varnothing,\{X=0\},\{X=1\},\Omega\}$$